# handling styling inside Div containers used across multiple pages

Tags: css, html, styles

I have tried to find the answer to this by searching but am coming up empty.  Basically I am unsure how to properly handle some CSS design.  I have a template that I use for many pages.  There are several containers that I need to style.  Lets say for example I have a div called "box 1" that I use on many different pages.  I have styled the lengths of  text boxes externally with css.  How can I now style  textboxes in different pages using the "box 1" div without overwriting my original style.  Is there someway to label these.  Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply multiple classes:

```
.box {
    background-color: red;
}

.box.new_style {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

If you create a div:

```
<div class="box">This is a box</div>
```

It will have a red background, then another div:

```
<div class="box new_style">This is a box</div>
```

It will have a red background AND bold text.

---

Since you mentioned multiple pages you could attach a class to the container or `body`, then use:

```
<body class="some_page">
    <div class="box">
       ....
```

Then:

```
.some_page .box { font-weight: bold; }
```

Comment: If you change properties of the class it will affect ALL elements, really the only way to do it is to have different classes.